VC++を利用した開発での3Dモデルなどのリソースの隠し方
私は現在VisualStudio2022とVulkan、C++を利用してゲームを作っています。
現在ゲームに必要なObjファイルやpngなどの画像ファイルをプログラム上で利用する際に、
tiny_obj_loaderとstb_imageを使っています。これらのどちらもファイルを読み込む際に、読み込む関数に目的のファイルのパスを引数として渡してファイルを読み込みます。なのでexeファイルとしてビルドした場合、そのexeファイルからそれらのファイルを読み込めるようにexeと同じディレクトリ上などに読み込むファイルを置かなければなりません。
私が利用しているObjファイルやpngファイルなどは、それらをそのままダウンロードできる形式でアップロードするのが禁止されています。(exe(ゲーム本体)、3Dモデル.obj、テクスチャ.png)このような状態でアップロードしてはいけない。
ですので、Objファイルやpngファイルなどをexeファイルに埋め込むなど、それらのファイルをそのままダウンロードできない形式にしたいです。VisualStudioでのリソースファイルを利用した方法は、読み込めるファイルの制限があるようなので、できれば現在利用しているファイルのパスを使ってファイルを読み込むライブラリをそのまま利用できるような、Objファイルやpngファイルの隠蔽の仕方があれば教えていただきたいです。

こちらの記事 バイナリファイルの埋め込みかた の最後にVC++プロジェクトでのデータ埋め込みがあって、リソースには既定のクラスだけでなく、ユーザ定義の任意のデータも追加できます。とあるようですが。あとここのサイトでも類似の記事があります。Visual StudioのC++開発において、バイナリファイルをプログラムに埋め込んで参照するにはどのような方法がありますでしょうか。

外部ライブラリを使用している場合、ライブラリの名前だけ書くのではなく、必ずバージョンや公式サイトのURLを記載するようにしてください。オープンソースの場合は公式リポジトリのURLを記載してください。

とりあえず、「Objファイル」というのはWavefront OBJ形式のことで、「tiny_obj_loader」「stb_image」というのは以下の外部ライブラリを使っているものと仮定します。

https://github.com/tinyobjloader/tinyobjloader/tree/v1.0.6

https://github.com/tinyobjloader/tinyobjloader/blob/v1.0.6/tiny_obj_loader.h


https://github.com/nothings/stb

https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h



また、ロードにはtinyobj::LoadObj()関数を使っているものと仮定します。
tinyobj::LoadObj()関数にはconst char *filenameを受け取るオーバーロードのほか、std::istream *inStreamを受け取るオーバーロードがあるようなので、まず任意のファイルまたはリソースからWavefront OBJ形式のテキストデータをプレーンなASCII文字列（std::string）としてメモリに読み込み、std::istringstreamオブジェクトを構築すれば、std::istreamとして渡すことができ、メモリ上の文字列ストリームからパースすることができるはずです。
（例えばZIPファイルのエントリとして圧縮・登録されているテキストファイルの1つをzlibでメモリに読み込んでstd::stringの形に展開し、std::istringstreamをかませてパースする、といったこともできます）

std::basic_istringstream<CharT,Traits,Allocator>::basic_istringstream - cppreference.com

ちなみに、このtinyobjloaderライブラリはC++のくせになぜか中途半端にC関数のようなインターフェイスを持つひどい設計になっていて、APIとして全然洗練されていないのでお勧めできません。Wavefront OBJ自体、データ交換を目的とした古いフォーマットであり、本格的なゲーム開発には向いていないので、将来的には別のバイナリフォーマットを使ったほうがよいと思います。
画像の読み込みのほうはstbi_load_from_memory()を使えば、同様にメモリ上に読み込んだファイル (in-memory file) からロードできるのでは？
stbi_ucはunsigned charのエイリアスなので、まず画像ファイルのバイナリデータを丸ごとメモリに読み込んでstd::vector<unsigned char>の形で保持しておき、入力としてstd::vector::data()とstd::vector::size()を渡すだけです。
Win32リソースを使う場合は後述の方法で埋め込んだ画像ファイルを探索し、LoadResource(), LockResource(), SizeofResource()を使います。

Win32リソースにはユーザー定義のデータを埋め込むことができます。

Resource-Definition Statements - Win32 apps | Microsoft Learn

User-Defined Resource - Win32 apps | Microsoft Learn



例えばPNG形式の場合、以下のようなカスタムリソースとして埋め込むことができます。MYRESTYPE_PNGのように、カスタムリソース種別typeIDは標準の予約済みリソース種別と衝突しない限り自由に命名でき、これをFindResource()の第3引数lpTypeに文字列として指定します。
// Resource.h
#define ID_MY_PNG_IMAGE1  1000

// 何らかのリソーススクリプト。
ID_MY_PNG_IMAGE1  MYRESTYPE_PNG  "res\\image1.png"

ユーザー定義のリソースは、プロジェクトのメインリソーススクリプト<ProjectName>.rcに直接記述するのではなく、通例res\<ProjectName>.rc2のような専用リソーススクリプトに分けて記述し、<ProjectName>.rcからインクルードします。
（例えばMFCプロジェクトウィザードはデフォルトでres\<ProjectName>.rc2を生成します）

Project Resource Files (C++) | Microsoft Learn

EXE本体ではなく、リソース専用のDLLに分離することもあります。

Creating a resource-only DLL | Microsoft Learn

ただし、データ保護（抽出防止）や省メモリの観点から、ゲーム用のメディアファイルのようなアセットはEXE/DLLのWin32リソースとしてそのまま埋め込むようなことはせず、難読化（暗号化）したいくつかのアーカイブファイルにまとめておき、特定のシーンで必要になったファイルのみアーカイブファイルからメモリに読み込んで利用するほうがよいです。多くの商用ゲームはそういった工夫をしています。

ありがとうございます こちらの方法を使います。

@siwameron 解決策になった回答であれば、「承認」をお願いします。まずはヘルプセンターの説明を読んでください。
自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？ - ヘルプセンター - スタック・オーバーフロー
